# Python Class, add 2D points

Tags: python, class, 2d

how can you add two values using `__add__` function

```
(1,2)+(2,3) = (3,5)



def __add__(self, other):
    return Point((lambda x,y:x+y),self,other)
```

is this the way to think?
What is the probable error!!

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your questions by clicking the check mark next to them. You should do this for your old questions too-- I see several of them have good answers you haven't accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's close, except you need to [`return NotImplemented`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) if it's not a `Point`:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Point):
        return NotImplemented
    return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I would probably do it this way:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Your question is a bit vague and you don't provide details about the `Point` class so it's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're asking.

Specifically, I don't understand the purpose of the lambda argument to the constructor.  I think I understand what it's doing, but I'm not sure I can see a situation in which that constructor would be a useful way to express an operation.